# Create button where I have a mouse click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to create a button which displays the number of the mouse click (the button should appear where I have the click) and after 10 seconds to remove the button. This is the code where I tried to solve the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    </head> 
    <body>
    </body> 
    <script type ="text/javascript"> 
    counter = 1; 

    document.onclick = function(e){
        var button =document.createElement('button');

        button.style.position ="fixed";
        button.style.marginLeft= e.screenX;
        button.style.marginTop = e.screenY;
        button.label =x;
       
        document.body.appendChild(button);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(button);
        }, 1000;
    };
    </script> 
</html>
```

Comment: Open the JavaScript console. Read the error messages. You've got a pretty obvious and basic syntax error.

Comment: To be more clear: `}, 1000;` needs to be `}, 1000);`. Also this is in milliseconds `1000` is 1 second, you will want `10000` for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will achieve the desired functionality of yours!

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  counter = 1;

  document.onclick = function(e) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.style.position = 'fixed';
    button.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    button.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    button.innerHTML = counter;
    counter++;

    document.body.appendChild(button);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.removeChild(button);
    }, 1000);
  };
</script>

</html>
```